# Post request with an image using Ktor client

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm having trouble sending an http request which has a File as one of the parameters in the body. The response returned by the API is not what I'm expecting so I figure something is wrong with the code.

```
suspend fun post(url: String, bodyParameters: MutableMap<String, Any>, headerParameters:
    MutableMap<String, String>? = null): HttpResponse?{

        val client = HttpClient()

        try {
            val call = client.call(url) {
                method = HttpMethod.Post
                body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    formData {
                        bodyParameters.forEach{(key, value) ->
                            when(value) {
                                is String -> {
                                    append(key, value)
                                }

                                is File -> {
                                    append(key, value.inputStream().asInput())
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            if(call.response.status.value == 500) {
                return null
            }
            return call.response
```

The response status that is being returned is what is expected when no File is being sent. Any ideas on why this doesn't work?
Are there any other ways to do this with Ktor?

Comment: What response are you getting in the image case?

Comment: Alexander Egger - The response I'm getting from the server has the status 401 which is the expected when no File is inserted. However, when I tested it on Postman it also returned an response json that I'm not able to read when using call.response.readText(). If I use the client.post<HttpResponse>(url) method with no parameters I can access that response json.. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Maybe you have to set the "Accept" header to "application/json"

Comment: That's not it unfortunately. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Could you install the `Logging` feature and provide some log? Maybe it's because the type of part with the file should be `FileItem` instead of just `BinaryItem`

Comment: @SérgioEduardo, were u able to sort the issue, if yes please share a sample request of multpart with ktor

Comment: There is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60373938/750510

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file using Ktor client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373937/how-to-upload-a-file-using-ktor-client)