# Cannot upload file to ktor server using ktor client

Tags: file-upload, ktor

I have setup server according to [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/uploads.html#receiving-files-using-multipart) and try to upload file using code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373937/how-to-upload-a-file-using-ktor-client):

```kotlin
val parts: List<PartData> = formData {
    append(
        "image",
        InputProvider { ins.asInput() },
        Headers.build {
            this[HttpHeaders.ContentType] = "image/png"
            this[HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition] = "filename=$name"
        }
    )
}
return HttpClient(Apache) {
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.DEFAULT
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }
}.submitFormWithBinaryData(formData = parts) {
    url("$baseUrl/images")
}
```

If I use it as is (without request Content-Type), then server fails: "Content-Type header is required for multipart processing".

If I try to add header, client fails: "Header Content-Type is controlled by the engine and cannot be set explicitly".

Then it's actually something strange happening.

According to client logs, it's sending content type:

```
REQUEST: http://localhost:8090/images
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
COMMON HEADERS
-> Accept: */*
-> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
CONTENT HEADERS
BODY Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-675255df42a752ee167beaab-5799548c6088f411-a7e8dc449d68ab028c44d80-42b
BODY START
[request body omitted]
...
```

But on server side headers are completly different:

```
Accept-Charset [UTF-8]
Accept [*/*]
User-Agent [Ktor client]
Transfer-Encoding [chunked]
Host [localhost:8090]
Connection [Keep-Alive]
```

On other hand I can successfully upload file using okhttp (and headers actually matches):

```kotlin
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    override fun log(message: String ) {
        println(message)
    }
})
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logging)
    .build()
val file = File("image.png")
val part: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.Companion.createFormData(
    "image",
    "image.png",
    file.asRequestBody("image/png".toMediaTypeOrNull())
)
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("http://localhost:8090/images")
    .post(MultipartBody.Builder().addPart(part).build())
    .build()
val res = client.newCall(request).execute()
res.body
```

Is it bug in ktor client or I missing something?

edit:

Both client and server versions is 1.4.1.
Corresponding gradle dependencies parts:

```
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:${ktor_version}")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:${ktor_version}")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8")

    ...

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-jackson:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.2")
```

route:

```kotlin
object ImagesRouter {

    fun Routing.images(imagesModule: ImagesModule) {
        route("images") {
            get("/{id}") {
                // ...
            }

            post {
                val multipart = call.receiveMultipart() // fails here   
                // ...             
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Look if this could be relatad: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1129

Comment: Your sample works fine when I make a request to `https://httpbin.org/post` with and without the `Content-Type` header. I've checked it with Ktor 1.3.2, 1.4.1, and 1.5.0. Could you please provide additional information about the version of Ktor and of your project's dependencies?

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks, but I have added logging after I had encountered the problem

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I have added versions and dependencies. I will try to create minimal reproducer this week

Comment: Oh, I have reduced minimal example exactly to reproducer in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1129, thank you...