# Put File as Binary with Ktor HttpClient in Kotlin Multiplatform Project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I have a multiplatform project in which api code is shared between iOS and Android.

There is "put" api to upload local audio file as Binary.

Ive created httpclient as follows

```
 val client = HttpClient {
        defaultRequest {
            url {
                protocol = ServiceConfiguration.protocol
                host = ServiceConfiguration.baseUrl
                port = ServiceConfiguration.port
            }
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }



        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                isLenient = true
            }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
    }
```

To put the object into api, I am doing as follows

```
val response = ServiceRequest.client.put<String>(
                body = File(path).readBytes()
            )
```

It works fine and uploads the byte array to backend. But instead of byte array I want to upload the file as plain binary.

To make it more clear, In Postman mac app we can upload file as binary . I need to do similar thing.

When I checked in Ktor, it shows only multi-part form data can be submitted as binary. But In my case it is Put request.

Please help.

Comment: did you try something along the lines of:
    suspend fun putMultipart(partData: List<PartData>) {
        httpClient.put<Unit>("url") {
            body = MultiPartFormDataContent(partData)
        }
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file using Ktor client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373937/how-to-upload-a-file-using-ktor-client)

Comment: I've found a similar question with an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373937/how-to-upload-a-file-using-ktor-client.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Thanks for the helpful comments, above mentioned urls are using multipart or part data.. But I needed to just put the file as binary body into the request and upload. turns out, With Ktor, we cant do that. I used platform specific libraries to do that. Thank you very much

Comment: @KishorekumarEK How are you getting this import File(path).readBytes() is it Java file in kotlin multiplatform?

Comment: @RaghavPai, No its a ByteArray Type for clarity I've replaced the line with File(path).readBytes() I pass the byteArray from android to this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no straightforward way to put file as binary with Ktor.

I had to go for platform Dependent approaches like OkHttpClient for Android and URLSession for iOS.